# Google Interview Questions

Tags: javascript

I have an interview with Google on Javascript and form verification. 
I have done a lot of preparation in terms of algorithms and general data structure. But how to prepare for an interview by a javascript team?

Please share some example and resources. 
Thanks

Comment: Many existing questions about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684917/what-questions-should-a-javascript-programmer-be-able-to-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069857/advanced-javascript-interview-questions

Comment: Check out this: https://github.com/khan4019/front-end-Interview-Questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [Douglas Crockford's](http://javascript.crockford.com/) resources on JavaScript, especially his Google tech talks called [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook).